# How can I create a directory tree in C++ on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, directory

I want an easy way to create multiple directories in C++ on Linux.

For example, I want to save a file lola.file in the directory:

```
/tmp/a/b/c
```

but if the directories are not there I want them to be created automagically. A working example would be perfect.

Comment: C++ does not have any built-in facilities for creating directories and trees *per se*. You will have to use C and system calls or an external library like Boost. C and system calls will be platform dependent.

Comment: @noloader Thanks a lot man.. but I think after 4 years I pretty much got my answer as you can see bellow in 13 different ways...

Comment: Yeah, I was surprised no one explicitly stated you cannot do it in C++ (assuming you wanted a portable method in C++ that worked on Linux). But you probably knew that ;). There were a lot of good suggestions for non-portable C code, though.

Comment: What is "C++/Linux"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's my university years in C++ on Linux :)

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Easy with Boost.Filesystem: [`create_directories`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#create_directories)

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
//...
boost::filesystem::create_directories("/tmp/a/b/c");
```

Returns: `true` if a new directory was created, otherwise `false`.

Comment: That's kind of nifty.  How big an overheard is there including boost in a C++ project?

Comment: It's nifty.. but won't work in my project.. it's an embedded linux system.. and I'm a noob so.. :)

Comment: Well, most boost libraries are header-only, meaning there is no overhead besides what you use. In the case of Boost.Filesystem, it requires compiling though. On my disk, the compiled library weighs ~60KB.

Comment: @Lipis: please precise what your embedded system is. I believe it should be available on pretty much every linux distribution.

Comment: @Benoit: I guess you're right... Maybe I'll try it at one point!

Comment: I'm starting to like Boost more and more every hour :)

Comment: Regarding on the C++11 compilers mentioned by @danijar, the comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12151364/693110) made it clearer:  `The <filesystem> header is not part of C++11; it is a proposal for C++ TR2 based on the Boost.Filesystem library. Visual C++ 2012 includes an implementation of the proposed library.`

Comment: boost::filesystem is not header-only: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604090/list-of-header-only-boost-libraries

Comment: This option requires you to compile the boost::filesystem, something that should not be recommended.

Comment: IMHO: In any project of mine that is meant to do something significant and stand the test of time, it is WELL worth the compile to have such a set of incredibly useful and powerful standardized tools as boost.  A ton of it has already made its way into standard C++, certainly with more to come.  Try it out, stick with it, you'll benefit if you have more than trivial needs and you do not want to reinvent the wheel.  :-)

Comment: Caveat: compile times definitely go up.

Comment: We have stdc++17 `fs::create_directories` now!

Comment: Compile time is overhead as well. It slows down code iteration.

Answer (score 97):

With C++17 or later, there's the standard header `<filesystem>` with
function
[`std::filesystem::create_directories`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory)
which should be used in modern C++ programs.
The C++ standard functions do not have the POSIX-specific explicit
permissions (mode) argument, though.

However, here's a C function that can be compiled with C++ compilers.

```c
/*
@(#)File:           mkpath.c
@(#)Purpose:        Create all directories in path
@(#)Author:         J Leffler
@(#)Copyright:      (C) JLSS 1990-2020
@(#)Derivation:     mkpath.c 1.16 2020/06/19 15:08:10
*/

/*TABSTOP=4*/

#include "posixver.h"
#include "mkpath.h"
#include "emalloc.h"

#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
/* "sysstat.h" == <sys/stat.h> with fixup for (old) Windows - inc mode_t */
#include "sysstat.h"

typedef struct stat Stat;

static int do_mkdir(const char *path, mode_t mode)
{
    Stat            st;
    int             status = 0;

    if (stat(path, &st) != 0)
    {
        /* Directory does not exist. EEXIST for race condition */
        if (mkdir(path, mode) != 0 && errno != EEXIST)
            status = -1;
    }
    else if (!S_ISDIR(st.st_mode))
    {
        errno = ENOTDIR;
        status = -1;
    }

    return(status);
}

/**
** mkpath - ensure all directories in path exist
** Algorithm takes the pessimistic view and works top-down to ensure
** each directory in path exists, rather than optimistically creating
** the last element and working backwards.
*/
int mkpath(const char *path, mode_t mode)
{
    char           *pp;
    char           *sp;
    int             status;
    char           *copypath = STRDUP(path);

    status = 0;
    pp = copypath;
    while (status == 0 && (sp = strchr(pp, '/')) != 0)
    {
        if (sp != pp)
        {
            /* Neither root nor double slash in path */
            *sp = '\0';
            status = do_mkdir(copypath, mode);
            *sp = '/';
        }
        pp = sp + 1;
    }
    if (status == 0)
        status = do_mkdir(path, mode);
    FREE(copypath);
    return (status);
}

#ifdef TEST

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/*
** Stress test with parallel running of mkpath() function.
** Before the EEXIST test, code would fail.
** With the EEXIST test, code does not fail.
**
** Test shell script
** PREFIX=mkpath.$$
** NAME=./$PREFIX/sa/32/ad/13/23/13/12/13/sd/ds/ww/qq/ss/dd/zz/xx/dd/rr/ff/ff/ss/ss/ss/ss/ss/ss/ss/ss
** : ${MKPATH:=mkpath}
** ./$MKPATH $NAME &
** [...repeat a dozen times or so...]
** ./$MKPATH $NAME &
** wait
** rm -fr ./$PREFIX/
*/

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int             i;

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            if (fork() == 0)
            {
                int rc = mkpath(argv[i], 0777);
                if (rc != 0)
                    fprintf(stderr, "%d: failed to create (%d: %s): %s\n",
                            (int)getpid(), errno, strerror(errno), argv[i]);
                exit(rc == 0 ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        int status;
        int fail = 0;
        while (wait(&status) != -1)
        {
            if (WEXITSTATUS(status) != 0)
                fail = 1;
        }
        if (fail == 0)
            printf("created: %s\n", argv[i]);
    }
    return(0);
}

#endif /* TEST */
```

The macros `STRDUP()` and `FREE()` are error-checking versions of
`strdup()` and `free()`, declared in `emalloc.h` (and implemented in
`emalloc.c` and `estrdup.c`).
The `"sysstat.h"` header deals with broken versions of `<sys/stat.h>`
and can be replaced by `<sys/stat.h>` on modern Unix systems (but there
were many issues back in 1990).
And `"mkpath.h"` declares `mkpath()`.

The change between v1.12 (original version of the answer) and v1.13
(amended version of the answer) was the test for `EEXIST` in
`do_mkdir()`.
This was pointed out as necessary by
[Switch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205938/switch) — thank
you, Switch.
The test code has been upgraded and reproduced the problem on a MacBook
Pro (2.3GHz Intel Core i7, running Mac OS X 10.7.4), and suggests that
the problem is fixed in the revision (but testing can only show the
presence of bugs, never their absence).
The code shown is now v1.16; there have been cosmetic or administrative
changes made since v1.13 (such as use `mkpath.h` instead of `jlss.h` and
include `<unistd.h>` unconditionally in the test code only).
It's reasonable to argue that `"sysstat.h"` should be replaced by
`<sys/stat.h>` unless you have an unusually recalcitrant system.

*(You are hereby given permission to use this code for any purpose with attribution.)*

This code is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq)
(Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `mkpath.c` and
`mkpath.h` (etc.) in the
[src/so-0067-5039](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/so-0067-5039)
sub-directory.

Comment: Ok... the result of that one exactly what I wanted..! Can someone tell me if this is faster than system("mkdir -p /tmp/a/b/c").. cause this is so much easier :)

Comment: It surely is faster than system. System has a lot of overhead involved. Basically, the process has to be forked, then at least two binaries have to be loaded (one will probably be in cache already), on of which will be yet another fork of the other, ...

Comment: I forgot: And then "mkdir -p" will do at least the same as the code posted above!

Comment: There's a subtle race condition in this code that I actually hit. It  only happens when multiple programs start up simultaneously and make the same folder path. The fix is to add `if (errno != EEXIST) { status = -1; }` when mkdir fails.

Comment: @Switch: Thanks.  That's the trouble with using `stat()` before `mkdir()`; it is a TOCTOU (time of check, time of use) problem.  I tried tickling the bug with a shell script running 13 processes in background creating the same 29-element path, and didn't manage to hit it.  Then I hacked the test program to fork 20 times and have each child try, and that managed to hit the bug. The fixed code will have `if (mkdir(path, mode) != 0 && errno != EEXIST) status = -1;`.  That doesn't show the bug.

Comment: Where can I find the jlss and emalloc libraries? My compiler errors out for these 2.

Comment: @DavidMerinos: they're headers (`jlss.h`, `emalloc.h`), not libraries.  However, the code is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `jlss.h`, `emalloc.c` and `emalloc.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.  You'll need `posixver.h` too, and a few others (`debug.h`, `stderr.c`, `stderr.h` — I think that's it, but what you need should all be in that directory).

Answer (score 42):

```
system("mkdir -p /tmp/a/b/c")
```

is the shortest way I can think of (in terms of the length of code, not necessarily execution time).

It's not cross-platform but will work under Linux.

Comment: IF your going to give the solution as a shell command, it would be well to mention system (3)

Comment: Don't forget you'll need to escape the path properly if it's not controlled by you. Otherwise you would create a huge security hole.

Comment: I wonder why people create so many APIs in WinAPI and Libc while you could create whole programs using system. Seriously why do this post has 42 upvotes, this is a major security issue and a terrible programming habit.

Answer (score 32):

Here is my example of code (it works for both Windows and Linux):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/stat.h> // stat
#include <errno.h>    // errno, ENOENT, EEXIST
#if defined(_WIN32)
#include <direct.h>   // _mkdir
#endif

bool isDirExist(const std::string& path)
{
#if defined(_WIN32)
    struct _stat info;
    if (_stat(path.c_str(), &info) != 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return (info.st_mode & _S_IFDIR) != 0;
#else 
    struct stat info;
    if (stat(path.c_str(), &info) != 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return (info.st_mode & S_IFDIR) != 0;
#endif
}

bool makePath(const std::string& path)
{
#if defined(_WIN32)
    int ret = _mkdir(path.c_str());
#else
    mode_t mode = 0755;
    int ret = mkdir(path.c_str(), mode);
#endif
    if (ret == 0)
        return true;

    switch (errno)
    {
    case ENOENT:
        // parent didn't exist, try to create it
        {
            int pos = path.find_last_of('/');
            if (pos == std::string::npos)
#if defined(_WIN32)
                pos = path.find_last_of('\\');
            if (pos == std::string::npos)
#endif
                return false;
            if (!makePath( path.substr(0, pos) ))
                return false;
        }
        // now, try to create again
#if defined(_WIN32)
        return 0 == _mkdir(path.c_str());
#else 
        return 0 == mkdir(path.c_str(), mode);
#endif

    case EEXIST:
        // done!
        return isDirExist(path);

    default:
        return false;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* ARGV[])
{
    for (int i=1; i<argc; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "creating " << ARGV[i] << " ... " << (makePath(ARGV[i]) ? "OK" : "failed") << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Usage:

```
$ makePath 1/2 folderA/folderB/folderC
creating 1/2 ... OK
creating folderA/folderB/folderC ... OK
```

Comment: I second that comment!  It is (surprisingly) not a trivial task to find a portable C++ way to create a directory. This answer needs more upvotes.

Comment: Under Windows, isDirExist does not work if the trailing character is a backslash. Always returns false.  I have to modify the code to: std::string dirPath(path); while ('\\' == *dirPath.rbegin()) dirPath.pop_back(); ... and then, of course, pass dirPath.c_str() in the call to _stat.

Comment: Windows API has "Non-ANSI names for compatibility" for `stat` (related to `__STDC__`) no need for the precompiler test.

Answer (score 28):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int status;
...
status = mkdir("/tmp/a/b/c", S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH);
```

From [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkdir).  You may have to do separate mkdirs for /tmp, /tmp/a, /tmp/a/b/ and then /tmp/a/b/c because there isn't an equivalent of the -p flag in the C api.  Be sure and ignore the EEXISTS errno while you're doing the upper level ones.

Comment: Fun fact: At least Solaris and HP/UX have mkdirp(), although it's clearly not optimal for portability.

Comment: that's the point.. that I don't want to call all these functions separately.

Comment: Calling mkdir a few times will be way, way faster than calling system once.

Comment: I don't understand what you are suggesting: calling mkdir 4 times with different arguments? `("/tmp/",...)`, `("/tmp/a/",...)`, `("/tmp/a/b/",...)`, `("/tmp/a/b/c/",...)`

Comment: @Antonio, that's exactly what I'm suggesting. 3 or 4 calls to `mkdir` are a lot more efficient than calling `system` once. However, if you have to make the `/tmp` directory, you've got bigger problems than I can help you with.

Comment: As it is, this doesn't answer in a generic way to the question. For example, in a function `create_directories` taking the path as input, it would require preliminary splitting the input path. In [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/675043/2436175), it's just a matter of concatenating 2 strings to create the system command call.

Comment: Splitting a string into directories is trivial string processing. I didn't bother showing people how to do that because that wasn't the question.

Comment: @PaulTomblin You didn't even show the *complete* code to answer the actual question. The complete code, includes all the calls to `mkdir` that I have mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: Again, it's pretty trivial to make the same call three times. The point is to give people enough information that they can write the code, not to write the code for them.

Answer (score 27):

It should be noted that starting from C++17 filesystem interface is part of the standard library. This means that one can have following to create directories:

```
#include <filesystem>

std::filesystem::create_directories("/a/b/c/d")
```

More info here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory

Additionally, with gcc, one needs to "-std=c++17" to CFLAGS. And "-lstdc++fs" to LDLIBS. The latter potentially is not going to be required in the future.

Comment: Should also work with new enough Visual C++ and "/std:c++latest". See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/05/07/announcing-msvc-conforms-to-the-c-standard/  and https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/296680/filesystem-is-not-a-member-of-std-1.html

Answer (score 11):

This is similar to the previous but works forward through the string instead of recursively backwards.  Leaves errno with the right value for last failure.  If there's a leading slash, there's an extra time through the loop which could have been avoided via one find_first_of() outside the loop or by detecting the leading / and setting pre to 1.  The efficiency is the same whether we get set up by a first loop or a pre loop call, and the complexity would be (slightly) higher when using the pre-loop call.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int
mkpath(std::string s,mode_t mode)
{
    size_t pos=0;
    std::string dir;
    int mdret;

    if(s[s.size()-1]!='/'){
        // force trailing / so we can handle everything in loop
        s+='/';
    }

    while((pos=s.find_first_of('/',pos))!=std::string::npos){
        dir=s.substr(0,pos++);
        if(dir.size()==0) continue; // if leading / first time is 0 length
        if((mdret=mkdir(dir.c_str(),mode)) && errno!=EEXIST){
            return mdret;
        }
    }
    return mdret;
}

int main()
{
    int mkdirretval;
    mkdirretval=mkpath("./foo/bar",0755);
    std::cout << mkdirretval << '\n';

}
```

Answer (score 9):

You said "C++" but everyone here seems to be thinking "Bash shell."

Check out the source code to gnu `mkdir`; then you can see how to implement the shell commands in C++.

Comment: Well system("mkdir...") should do the trick on linux. It's not cross-platform though.

Comment: I second what @MartinCarpenter says

Comment: the question is confusing...

Answer (score 7):

```
bool mkpath( std::string path )
{
    bool bSuccess = false;
    int nRC = ::mkdir( path.c_str(), 0775 );
    if( nRC == -1 )
    {
        switch( errno )
        {
            case ENOENT:
                //parent didn't exist, try to create it
                if( mkpath( path.substr(0, path.find_last_of('/')) ) )
                    //Now, try to create again.
                    bSuccess = 0 == ::mkdir( path.c_str(), 0775 );
                else
                    bSuccess = false;
                break;
            case EEXIST:
                //Done!
                bSuccess = true;
                break;
            default:
                bSuccess = false;
                break;
        }
    }
    else
        bSuccess = true;
    return bSuccess;
}
```

Comment: it's the best solution for me! Thank you!)))

Comment: maybe it's a dump question, but what is the "::" prefix before mkdir?

Comment: Found the answer, the :: ensures that resolution occurs from the global namespace http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269034/what-is-the-meaning-of-prepended-double-colon

Answer (score 5):

So I need `mkdirp()` today, and found the solutions on this page overly complicated.
Hence I wrote a fairly short snippet, that easily be copied in for others who
stumble upon this thread an wonder why we need so many lines of code.

**mkdirp.h**

```
#ifndef MKDIRP_H
#define MKDIRP_H

#include <sys/stat.h>

#define DEFAULT_MODE      S_IRWXU | S_IRGRP |  S_IXGRP | S_IROTH | S_IXOTH

/** Utility function to create directory tree */
bool mkdirp(const char* path, mode_t mode = DEFAULT_MODE);

#endif // MKDIRP_H
```

**mkdirp.cpp**

```
#include <errno.h>

bool mkdirp(const char* path, mode_t mode) {
  // const cast for hack
  char* p = const_cast<char*>(path);

  // Do mkdir for each slash until end of string or error
  while (*p != '\0') {
    // Skip first character
    p++;

    // Find first slash or end
    while(*p != '\0' && *p != '/') p++;

    // Remember value from p
    char v = *p;

    // Write end of string at p
    *p = '\0';

    // Create folder from path to '\0' inserted at p
    if(mkdir(path, mode) == -1 && errno != EEXIST) {
      *p = v;
      return false;
    }

    // Restore path to it's former glory
    *p = v;
  }

  return true;
}
```

If you don't like const casting and temporarily modifying the string, just do a `strdup()` and `free()` it afterwards.

Comment: Posted to a gist too, so I don't forget where I put it next time a need it :)
https://gist.github.com/jonasfj/7797272

Comment: It is evil to try modifying a string that is passed as a constant.  All else apart, it is likely to lead to dramatic failures if it is ever passed a string literal.

Comment: Perfectly right.... this is actually bad... probably strcpy would make this better...

Answer (score 3):

Since this post is ranking high in Google for "Create Directory Tree", I am going to post an answer that will work for Windows — this will work using Win32 API compiled for UNICODE or MBCS. This is ported from Mark's code above.

Since this is Windows we are working with, directory separators are BACK-slashes, not forward slashes. If you would rather have forward slashes, change **`'\\'`** to **`'/'`**

It will work with:

```
c:\foo\bar\hello\world
```

and

```
c:\foo\bar\hellp\world\
```

(i.e.: does not need trailing slash, so you don't have to check for it.)

Before saying "Just use **SHCreateDirectoryEx()** in Windows", note that **SHCreateDirectoryEx()** is deprecated and could be removed at any time from future versions of Windows.

```
bool CreateDirectoryTree(LPCTSTR szPathTree, LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes = NULL){
    bool bSuccess = false;
    const BOOL bCD = CreateDirectory(szPathTree, lpSecurityAttributes);
    DWORD dwLastError = 0;
    if(!bCD){
        dwLastError = GetLastError();
    }else{
        return true;
    }
    switch(dwLastError){
        case ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS:
            bSuccess = true;
            break;
        case ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND:
            {
                TCHAR szPrev[MAX_PATH] = {0};
                LPCTSTR szLast = _tcsrchr(szPathTree,'\\');
                _tcsnccpy(szPrev,szPathTree,(int)(szLast-szPathTree));
                if(CreateDirectoryTree(szPrev,lpSecurityAttributes)){
                    bSuccess = CreateDirectory(szPathTree,lpSecurityAttributes)!=0;
                    if(!bSuccess){
                        bSuccess = (GetLastError()==ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS);
                    }
                }else{
                    bSuccess = false;
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            bSuccess = false;
            break;
    }

    return bSuccess;
}
```

Comment: One little mod - if the path contains backslashes this doesn't work.  Here:

`  LPCTSTR szLast = _tcsrchr(szPathTree, '\\');`

You just need to add this:

```  if (nullptr == szLast)
  {
   szLast = _tcsrchr(szPathTree, '/');
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. What happens if a path is mixed? i.e.: `c:\this\is\a/mixed/path\of\slashes` Typically Windows slashes are backslashes. What should happen is the caller should sanitize the path and ensure all slashes are proper before calling this method.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an old question but it shows up high on google search results and the answers provided here are not really in C++ or are a bit too complicated.

Please note that in my example createDirTree() is very simple because all the heavy lifting (error checking, path validation) needs to be done by createDir() anyway. Also createDir() should return true if directory already exists or the whole thing won't work.

Here's how I would do that in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool createDir(const std::string dir)
{
    std::cout << "Make sure dir is a valid path, it does not exist and create it: "
              << dir << std::endl;
    return true;
}

bool createDirTree(const std::string full_path)
{
    size_t pos = 0;
    bool ret_val = true;

    while(ret_val == true && pos != std::string::npos)
    {
        pos = full_path.find('/', pos + 1);
        ret_val = createDir(full_path.substr(0, pos));
    }

    return ret_val;
}

int main()
{
    createDirTree("/tmp/a/b/c");
    return 0;
}
```

Of course createDir() function will be system-specific and there are already enough examples in other answers how to write it for linux, so I decided to skip it.

Answer (score 2):

So many approaches has been described here but most of them need hard coding of your path into your code.
There is an easy solution for that problem, using QDir and QFileInfo, two classes of Qt framework. Since your already in Linux environment it should be easy to use Qt.

```
QString qStringFileName("path/to/the/file/that/dont/exist.txt");
QDir dir = QFileInfo(qStringFileName).dir();
if(!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkpath(dir.path());
}
```

Make sure you have write access to that Path.

Answer (score 1):

If dir does not exist, create it:

```
boost::filesystem::create_directories(boost::filesystem::path(output_file).parent_path().string().c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's C/C++ recursive function that makes use of `dirname()` to traverse bottom-up the directory tree. It will stop as soon as it finds an existing ancestor.

```
#include <libgen.h>
#include <string.h>

int create_dir_tree_recursive(const char *path, const mode_t mode)
{
    if (strcmp(path, "/") == 0) // No need of checking if we are at root.
        return 0;

    // Check whether this dir exists or not.
    struct stat st;
    if (stat(path, &st) != 0 || !S_ISDIR(st.st_mode))
    {
        // Check and create parent dir tree first.
        char *path2 = strdup(path);
        char *parent_dir_path = dirname(path2);
        if (create_dir_tree_recursive(parent_dir_path, mode) == -1)
            return -1;

        // Create this dir.
        if (mkdir(path, mode) == -1)
            return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have C++17 yet and look for a platform agnostic solution, use [ghc::filesystem](https://github.com/gulrak/filesystem). The header-ony code is compatible to C++17 (in fact a backport) and easy to migrate later on.

Answer (score -1):

```
mkdir -p /dir/to/the/file

touch /dir/to/the/file/thefile.ending
```

Comment: the `-p` option is what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

The others got you the right answer, but I thought I'd demonstrate another neat thing you can do:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/a/{b,c}/d
```

Will create the following paths:

```
/tmp/a/b/d
/tmp/a/c/d
```

The braces allow you to create multiple directories at once on the same level of the hierarchy, whereas the `-p` option means "create parent directories as needed".

Comment: after seeing Paul's answer, I realize that I (and a lot of other people) misunderstood the question...

Comment: If somebody can Just update this by changing to system("mkdir -p /tmp/a/{b,c}/d"), cause the questions is not about doing it in shell.. but through C++.

Comment: I think {a,b} will work in both sh-derived and csh-derived shells.  I'm not sure if it will work in a system() command, though.

Comment: @Lipis: doing that via system() is not a good solution to the OP's question.  @Andy: I'd never considered that before, but I just tested it by replacing "mkdir -p" with "echo" and it prints out "/tmp/a/b/d /tmp/a/c/d", which suggests it is the shell doing it, not mkdir.

Comment: @rmeador: if it's not a good solution, do you have something else to suggest? I want to do that through C++... that's my issue not how to do that through shell..

Comment: @Lipis: there are plenty of other answers here that suggest how to do it through C++.  I'm rather fond of Boost, so I like Benoît's answer.  Paul's solution should also work, if your embedded system is very constrained.  Btw, sorry for not noticing that you ARE the OP in my last comment :)

Comment: Note that strict POSIX shells (`dash` etc) do not support brace expansion.