# dll function name is same with already existing MFC function

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am not very familiar with C++ and here I am confronted with an error which I couldn't find answer from web.

I am trying to compile an example code which imports functions from a dll.

I am using VS 2010 Professional.

The problem is I get an error message saying:

error C2660: 'CDialog::Initialize': function does not take 4 arguments.

When I look at the 'Initilize()' function, I see that actually it is not a CDialog:: function but something completely different function from the dll, where the header file is include in the .cpp.  It's the compiler misunderstanding it to CDialog:: and I see that since the class of the function in which the Initialize() is being called is actually inherited from CDialog.

What would be the simplest fix for this problem ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the correct function to be called with `Namespace::Initialize()` or `Class::Initialize()`, or just `::Initialize()` if the function is not a member of any namespace or class.

Comment: thanks, however all I see is the header file for that function. What can I do then ?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You probably just need to change the line where the compiler is complaining.

Comment: There is no namespace or Class for that function. All I see for the function declaration is in a header file and probably the function is in directly called from dll.

Comment: So on the line with compile error, try just changing `Initialize` to `::Initialize`.

Comment: thank!I thought that ::Initialize would really tell compiler that this function belongs to CDialog.. how did adding :: make compiler understand it belongs to the dll ???

Comment: for other novices like me, here I link the answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269034/what-is-the-meaning-of-prepended-double-colon-to-class-name