# What does prepending "::" to a function call do in C++?

Tags: c++, syntax, namespaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the meaning of prepended double colon “::” to class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269034/what-is-the-meaning-of-prepended-double-colon-to-class-name)

I have been looking at a legacy C++ code and it had something like this:

```
::putenv(local_tz_char);
::tzset();
```

What does this syntax of prepending "::" to the function calls mean? Google-fu is failing me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that the functions `putenv()` and `tzset()` will be looked up by the compiler in the global namespace.

**Example**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//global function
void foo()
{
    cout << "This function will be called by bar()";
}

namespace lorem
{
    void foo()
    {
        cout << "This function will not be called by bar()";
    }

    void bar()
    {
        ::foo();
    }
}

int main()
{
    lorem::bar(); //will print "This function will be called by bar()"
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Also known as [Scope resolution operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator)

> In C++ is used to define the already declared member functions (in the
>   header file with the .hpp or the .h extension) of a particular class.
>   In the .cpp file one can define the usual global functions or the
>   member functions of the class. To differentiate between the normal
>   functions and the member functions of the class, one needs to use the
>   scope resolution operator (::) in between the class name and the
>   member function name i.e. ship::foo() where ship is a class and foo()
>   is a member function of the class ship.

Example from Wikipedia:

```
#include <iostream>

// Without this using statement cout below would need to be std::cout
using namespace std; 

int n = 12; // A global variable

int main() {
  int n = 13; // A local variable
  cout << ::n << endl; // Print the global variable: 12
  cout << n   << endl; // Print the local variable: 13
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There was a discussion yesterday (+ a year) on a similar question.  Perhaps you can find a more indepth answer here.

[What is the meaning of prepended double colon "::"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269034/what-is-the-meaning-of-prepended-double-colon-to-class-name)

Comment: You should have flagged this as a duplicate.

Comment: I'm not sure how to flag a post or how to add an answer under the question like you did.  Might have something to do with not having enough rep to edit.

Comment: @stanek - +1 to raise the rep :)

Comment: +1, now you have enough rep to upvote *and* flag posts :). You need 50 rep to comment everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

It means: look up the function in the global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

It will use the specifically unqualified name (as opposed to anything imported with the `using` keyword).

Answer (score 0):

the `::` is the scope resolution operator, it tells the compiler in what scope to find the function.

For instance if you have a function with a local variable `var` and you have a global variable of the same name, you can choose to access the global one by prepending the scope resolution operator:

```
int var = 0;

void test() {
    int var = 5;
    cout << "Local: " << var << endl;
    cout << "Global: " << ::var << endl;
}
```

The IBM C++ compiler documentation puts it like this ([source](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp7l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc05cplr175.htm)):

> The :: (scope resolution) operator is used to qualify hidden names so
>   that you can still use them. You can use the unary scope operator if a
>   namespace scope or global scope name is hidden by an explicit
>   declaration of the same name in a block or class.

The same can be done for methods inside a class and versions of the same name outside. If you wanted to access a variable, function or class in a specific namespace you could access it like this: `<namespace>::<variable|function|class>`

One thing to note though, even though it is an operator it is not one of the operators that can be overloaded.