# C++ function output

Tags: c++, function, parameters, reference, scope

I'm looking few exercise from university about C++ and I found out this exercise:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int x = -2;

int h(int &x) {
    x = 2 * x;
    return x;
}

int g(int f) {
    return x;
}

int &f(int &x) {
    x += ::x; 
    return x;
}

int main() {
    int x = 6;
    f(::x) = h(x);
    cout << f(x) << endl;
    cout << g(x) << endl;
    cout << h(x) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is :

```
24
12
48
```

Can anyone explain me how do I get this output?

And how does `f(::x) = h(x);` work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `::x` refers to global `int x`, rather than to local `x`.

   <sup>See: [What is the meaning of prepended double colon “::” to class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269034/what-is-the-meaning-of-prepended-double-colon-to-class-name)</sup>
2. Function signatures differ (either pass `x` by value or reference). The former makes a copy, later does *not* and changes on `int &x` will reflect on whatever `x` refers to (what you pass as an argument).

   <sup>See: [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)</sup>
3. If you have `int &` as a return type, you will be able to make changes through this reference it returns to whatever was passed to `f` (by reference).

Think about how the code works, bearing in mind the aforementioned.

Comment: suppose we passed x local to f whate wille be the output ? i mean f(x)=h(x);

Comment: That behavior is not defined by the standard - order in which `f` or `h` are executed.

Comment: @said Did you accept and un-accept my answer? Why? :D

Answer (score 1):

Remember that local variables hide global variables? What you have here is that principle in action.

Consider the function

```
int &f(int &x) {
    x += ::x; 
    return x;
}
```

Here `int &x` passed as arguments is local to the function; where as `::x` in the function refers to the global variable x.

By the way, `::` is called the scope resolution operator and is used for many other purposes as well in C++.