# Does ::myFunction() belongs to global namespace?

Tags: c++, function, scope, namespaces

I know in C++, we use `::` to qualify the namespace for a variable or function, like `myNamespace::a`. But I notice some usages like `::myFunction()`. Does it mean the function belongs to the global namespace?

Comment: This just ensures that resolution occurs in the global namespace instead of the namespace you are in. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269034/what-is-the-meaning-of-prepended-double-colon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the code compiles, then yes, `::myFunction()` is referencing the global declaration of `myFunction`.

This is most commonly used when a local definition shadows your global definition:

```
namespace local {
    int myFunction() {}; // local namespace definition
};
int myFunction() {}; // global definition.
using namespace local;

int main() {
    // myFunction(); // ambiguous two definitions of myFunction in current scope.
    local::myFunction(); // uses local::myFunction();
    ::myFunction(); // uses global myfunction();
```

Comment: @Leon, yes, fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it means the variable, type or function following it must be available in the global namespace.

It can be used for example when something is shadowed by a local definition:

```
struct S {
  int i;
};

void f() {
  struct S {
    double d;
  };

  S a;
  ::S b;

  static_assert(sizeof(a) != sizeof(b), "should be different types");
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [`type_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) and [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) to get around types that have the same size. eg: `static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(a),decltype(b)>::value, "should be different types");`