# double colon after class name (declaration) - what does that mean?

Tags: c++

I've been wondering what does the following mean (code snippet taken from [cppreference pimpl](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl))

```
class widget::impl {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^

   ...
};
```

What does `a_class::another_class` mean? Is that a namespace? Or is that an inner class declared out-of-the-main-class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of prepended double colon "::"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269034/what-is-the-meaning-of-prepended-double-colon)

Comment: @Badda: "prepended" means "before", not "between" or "after". (IOW, not a duplicate. The C++ grammar is very much order-sensitive.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Or is that an inner class declared out-of-the-main-class?

Bingo. To be super clear, iit's actually an inner class *defined* outside the enclosing class.

It's a handy trick if you want a class with member-like access to your class as an implementation detail, but do not want to publish that nested class's definition to the clients of your class.

Answer (score 5):

The `::` operator is the [scope resolution operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers#Qualified_identifiers). It qualifies the scope of an expression. In your case, it qualifies the expression `class impl` with the scope `widget`, meaning the class `impl` that belongs to `widget`. Consider the following example which defines two `impl` classes at different scopes :

```
// global impl
class impl;

class widget
{
    // widget's impl
    class impl;
};

class widget::impl
{
    // Define widget's impl
};

class impl
{
    // Define global impl
};
```

The scope resolution operator allows you to clearly declare which class you are defining.

Answer (score 1):

It is an inner class.

```
 class Widget
  {
    // ...

  private:
    class impl;           

  };

  // Then, typically in a separate implementation file:
  class Widget::impl
  {
  public:
    // ...
    T1 t1_;
    T2 t2_;
  };
```

Comment: :-) auto_ptr is depricated

Answer (score 0):

Could be the declaration of forward declaration of inner class e.g.:

```
class A{
 class B;

};

class A::B {

};
```