# I don't how the different between functon socket(...) and ::socket(...) in windows programme

Tags: windows, networking

Iam a linux programmer and now I start to code in windows evniment, Recently I try to wirte a simple network process,I found someone use socket(...) in code and someone use ::socket(...),I want to kown the different of the both way.Could someone give me a help?

Comment: Please tag a language ([tag:c++]?).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of prepended double colon "::"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269034/what-is-the-meaning-of-prepended-double-colon)

Comment: Must be C++ _sample_ code.  @zero, `::` is often just a precaution, see the link that Johnny provided.