# How to interpret using A = ::B::C<::D::E, F> statement in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces

I am unable to understand the below statement and also how to use it?
Statement

```
using A = ::B::C<::D::E, F>
```

Following are the things, I would like to know:

1. My understanding is that using is a keyword for aliasing. So instead of `::B::C<::D::E, F>`, I can use A. Is this correct?
2. What is the role of :: before B? As far as I know B is a namespace.
3. Does :: before B and :: before D imply same thing?
4. What does angular bracket <> do? Can I assume it as function () with 2 arguments?
5. How to use A? can I use A like we use functions? Something like A(G, H)?

I have good understanding of basic c++ i.e. loops, arrays, functions, basic classes, basic inheritance etc. In other words, things present in C programming language along with basic OOPs.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Be carfull, "aliasing" in C++/C have a special meaning (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

Comment: One question per question please! And note there are several duplicates available for some you ask.

Comment: Get a good book from [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: `::B::C<::D::E, F>` is probably a class template. For type "C" in global namespace "B", with first template argument being a type "E" from global namespace "D", and "F" being a type from an unspecified namespace. And then "A" is an alias for the more complex type on the right.

Comment: It means you need to work with people who are better at choosing expressive names for things.

Comment: I hope the reason for that is the OP obfuscated the code to remove the expressive names for security / IP purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So instead of ::B::C<::D::E, F>, I can use A. Is this correct?

Yes

> What is the role of :: before B? As far as I know B is a namespace.

It's specifies that B should be the first level of namespace. [More info here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269034/what-is-the-meaning-of-prepended-double-colon)

> Does :: before B and :: before D imply same thing?

Yes

> What does angular bracket <> do? Can I assume it as function () with 2 arguments?

It's a [template](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates)

> How to use A? can I use A like we use functions? Something like A(G, H)?

In this context using is a [type alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) so `::B::C<::D::E, F>` must be a type. You will use A the same way you use `::B::C<::D::E, F>`.

Comment: *"How to use A? can I use A like we use functions?"*, not like a function but like the **type** , something like `A a{/*..*/};`.

Comment: true, updated.  :)