# How to read / write files to directories in C?

Tags: c, file-io

I need to write a binary file to some specified directory using a C program. But, while writing I want to make sure that if the directory structure does not exist it should create one for me.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Are you familiar with `readdir(3)` and `mkdir(2)`?

Comment: Here you can find solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675039/how-can-i-create-directory-tree-in-c-linux

Comment: As far as I know, there exists no wholly portable way to handle directories.  What platform are you on?

Comment: There is a C solution (provided by YT) at the question referenced by @Yob; that question is for C++, though, so it isn't quite a direct duplicate of this question.

Comment: Enjoy the fish! I amended my post only because I found it strange that you didn't accept my correct answer in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check whether the leaf directory exists, using `stat()`, and iteratively create directories in a top-down manner, using `mkdir()`. Or you may even abandon the check and start with a directory creation - it will just fail with bunch of `EEXIST` errors if your directories are already there. This is just an *easy way*.

If you're concerned about correctness, there is a *better way*. You should use `openat()` on subsequent available components (directories) of the desired path and `mkdirat()` to create lacking ones. That way you can avoid possible races. In the end, you should open your file using `openat()` too.

Check relevant [manpages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/dir_section_2.html) to see how you should use mentioned system calls.

---

If the above rod was not sufficiently long enough for you, then below you can find my simple Linux-flavored fish. `xopen()` function allows you to open the file in a given path, creating directories along the way.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* Look out! It modifies pathname! */
int xopen(char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode, mode_t dirmode)
{
    int fd, errsv;
    int dirfd = AT_FDCWD;
    char *ptr = pathname;

    while (*ptr == '/')
        ptr++;
    for (;;) {
        strsep(&ptr, "/");
        if (ptr == NULL) {
            fd = openat(dirfd, pathname, flags, mode);
            break;
        }
        while (*ptr == '/')
            ptr++;
        if (*ptr == '\0') {
            errno = EISDIR;
            fd = -1;
            break;
        }
        if ((fd = mkdirat(dirfd, pathname, dirmode)) < 0 && errno != EEXIST)
            break;
        if ((fd = openat(dirfd, pathname, O_DIRECTORY)) < 0)
            break;
        if (dirfd != AT_FDCWD)
            close(dirfd);
        dirfd = fd;
        pathname = ptr;
    }
    errsv = errno;
    if (dirfd != AT_FDCWD)
        close(dirfd);
    errno = errsv;

    return fd;
}
```