# What Boost package should I search for with cmake to include code from Boost Functional?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

In my code, I want to make use of `boost::hash<pair<int, int>>`, for which I need to:

```
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
```

I use the `cmake` to build my project. What package should I request with `find_package` in `CMakeLists.txt`? Right now I have: `find_package(Boost COMPONENTS program_options regex REQUIRED)`. I don't have any errors, but I suspect the reason for that is that I have all the boost libraries installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functional is a header only library, so you don't need add anything, because header only libraries will not be linked. See [Which boost libraries are header-only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604090/list-of-header-only-boost-libraries) also or http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#header-only-libraries.

Comment: So I only need to use `find_package` with libraries that need to be built?

What if this header was the only thing I used from Boost? Shouldn't I configure `cmake` to look for the requirements of the project? (I'm a bit confused by what `cmake` can actually, because I've recently switched to it from `autotools`).

Comment: This is more a question what boost can do than cmake, but you only need find_package in conjunction with build libs. Header only libraries will not be linked, thus they don't need to be added: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#header-only-libraries