# How to determine the Boost library names for CMake

Tags: boost, cmake

I am trying to figure out what components to `Find` in CMakeList.txt for `boost` libraries.

I looked at this directory `/usr/local/include/boost`. And I randomly pick some of the folders and try to use `FIND_PACKAGE`. These following all works well.

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS thread system log log_setup
                    signals graph memory_order program_options REQUIRED)
```

The particular one that I am using is `property_tree`. It is not working and produces the following error message:

> CMake Error at /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.1/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1182 (message):
>
> Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.
>
> Boost version: 1.55.0
>
> Boost include path: /usr/local/include
>
> Could not find the following static Boost libraries:
>
> ```
>     boost_property_tree
> ```

Could anyone explain how or where I can find the proper library names for boost?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `COMPONENTS` part of `FIND_PACKAGE` only searches for compiled libraries. It is not able to check for the header-only libraries that comprise a major part of Boost. There are only a few libraries that require linking (mostly those that perform platform-specific things).

From your examples, only `thread`, `signals` (in contrast to `signals2` which is header-only), `system` and `program_options` need to be build beforehand and then linked with your program. For the rest, it is sufficient to include the relevant header files .

Thus, it is sufficient to add `${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}` to the include directories of your target.

See here for a list of libraries of these libraries [Which boost libraries are header-only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604090/list-of-header-only-boost-libraries)

Comment: Boost Graph is not header-only for some features (like `read_graphviz`)

Answer (score 1):

If boost library is compiled, then component name is basically lowercase name of library without prefixes and suffixes (for example for boost_system-vc141-mt-x64-1_66.lib it would be 'system')

Also see here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/module/FindBoost.html