# CMake doesn't find Boost library property_tree

Tags: c++, windows, boost, cmake

I'm trying to cross compile a project which require boost `property_tree` but I'm having trouble with the CMake on windows.

On my system, boost is located at `C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_66_0` and the  headers file are located in the `boost` subdirectory. I therefore set those in my CMakeLists.txt

```
SET (BOOST_ROOT "C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_66_0")
SET (BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "${BOOST_ROOT}/boost")

SET(Boost_DEBUG ON)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS
             property_tree )
```

But Cmake give me the following error:

```
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1078 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.65.1;1.65.0;1.65;1.64.0;1.64;1.63.0;1.63;1.62.0;1.62;1.61.0;1.61;1.60.0;1.60;1.59.0;1.59;1.58.0;1.58;1.57.0;1.57;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.0;1.48;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46;1.45.0;1.45;1.44.0;1.44;1.43.0;1.43;1.42.0;1.42;1.41.0;1.41;1.40.0;1.40;1.39.0;1.39;1.38.0;1.38;1.37.0;1.37;1.36.1;1.36.0;1.36;1.35.1;1.35.0;1.35;1.34.1;1.34.0;1.34;1.33.1;1.33.0;1.33
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1080 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = TRUE
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1082 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = 
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1084 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = 
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1086 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = 
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1088 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = 
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1156 ] Declared as CMake or Environmental Variables:
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1158 ]   BOOST_ROOT = C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_66_0
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1160 ]   BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_66_0/boost
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1162 ]   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = 
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1164 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.65.1;1.65.0;1.65;1.64.0;1.64;1.63.0;1.63;1.62.0;1.62;1.61.0;1.61;1.60.0;1.60;1.59.0;1.59;1.58.0;1.58;1.57.0;1.57;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.0;1.48;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46;1.45.0;1.45;1.44.0;1.44;1.43.0;1.43;1.42.0;1.42;1.41.0;1.41;1.40.0;1.40;1.39.0;1.39;1.38.0;1.38;1.37.0;1.37;1.36.1;1.36.0;1.36;1.35.1;1.35.0;1.35;1.34.1;1.34.0;1.34;1.33.1;1.33.0;1.33
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1263 ] location of version.hpp: C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_66_0/boost/version.hpp
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1287 ] version.hpp reveals boost 1.66.0
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1373 ] guessed _boost_COMPILER = -vc141;-vc140
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1383 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = -mt
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1427 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = -
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1429 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = -gd
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1491 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_66_0/lib;C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_66_0/stage/lib;C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_66_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_66_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_66_0/lib;C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_66_0/../lib;C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_66_0/stage/lib;C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_66_0/../lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_66_0/../lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_65_1/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_65_1/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_65_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_65_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_65/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_65/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_64_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_64_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_64/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_64/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_63_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_63_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_63/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_63/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_62_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_62_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_62/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_62/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_61_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_61_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_61/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_61/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_60_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_60_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_60/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_60/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_59_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_59_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_59/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_59/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_58_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_58_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_58/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_58/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_57_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_57_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_57/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_57/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_56_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_56_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_56/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_56/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_55_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_55_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_55/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_55/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_54_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_54_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_54/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_54/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_53_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_53_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_53/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_53/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_52_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_52_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_52/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_52/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_51_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_51_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_51/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_51/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_50_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_50_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_50/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_50/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_49_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_49_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_49/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_49/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_48_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_48_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_48/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_48/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_47_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_47_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_47/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_47/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_46_1/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_46_1/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_46_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_46_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_46/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_46/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_45_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_45_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_45/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_45/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_44_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_44_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_44/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_44/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_43_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_43_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_43/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_43/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_42_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_42_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_42/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_42/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_41_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_41_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_41/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_41/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_40_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_40_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_40/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_40/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_39_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_39_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_39/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_39/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_38_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_38_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_38/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_38/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_37_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_37_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_37/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_37/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_36_1/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_36_1/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_36_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_36_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_36/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_36/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_35_1/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_35_1/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_35_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_35_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_35/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_35/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_34_1/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_34_1/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_34_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_34_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_34/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_34/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_33_1/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_33_1/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_33_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_33_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_33/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_33/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/boost/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/boost/lib32-msvc-14.0;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib_boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG   = C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_66_0/lib;C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_66_0/stage/lib;C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_66_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_66_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_66_0/lib;C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_66_0/../lib;C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_66_0/stage/lib;C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_66_0/../lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_66_0/../lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_65_1/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_65_1/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_65_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_65_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_65/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_65/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_64_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_64_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_64/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_64/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_63_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_63_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_63/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_63/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_62_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_62_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_62/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_62/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_61_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_61_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_61/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_61/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_60_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_60_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_60/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_60/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_59_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_59_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_59/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_59/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_58_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_58_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_58/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_58/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_57_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_57_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_57/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_57/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_56_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_56_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_56/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_56/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_55_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_55_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_55/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_55/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_54_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_54_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_54/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_54/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_53_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_53_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_53/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_53/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_52_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_52_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_52/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_52/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_51_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_51_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_51/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_51/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_50_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_50_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_50/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_50/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_49_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_49_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_49/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_49/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_48_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_48_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_48/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_48/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_47_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_47_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_47/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_47/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_46_1/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_46_1/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_46_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_46_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_46/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_46/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_45_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_45_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_45/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_45/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_44_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_44_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_44/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_44/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_43_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_43_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_43/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_43/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_42_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_42_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_42/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_42/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_41_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_41_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_41/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_41/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_40_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_40_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_40/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_40/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_39_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_39_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_39/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_39/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_38_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_38_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_38/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_38/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_37_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_37_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_37/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_37/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_36_1/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_36_1/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_36_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_36_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_36/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_36/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_35_1/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_35_1/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_35_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_35_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_35/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_35/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_34_1/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_34_1/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_34_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_34_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_34/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_34/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_33_1/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_33_1/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_33_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_33_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_33/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_33/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/boost/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/boost/lib32-msvc-14.0;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib
CMake Warning at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:801 (message):
  New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported
  targets
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:907 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1542 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)


CMake Warning at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1610 (message):
  No header defined for property_tree; skipping header check
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)


[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1641 ] Searching for PROPERTY_TREE_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_property_tree-vc141-mt-1_66;boost_property_tree-vc141-mt;boost_property_tree-vc140-mt-1_66;boost_property_tree-vc140-mt;boost_property_tree-mt-1_66;boost_property_tree-mt;boost_property_tree
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1692 ] Searching for PROPERTY_TREE_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_property_tree-vc141-mt-gd-1_66;boost_property_tree-vc141-mt-gd;boost_property_tree-vc140-mt-gd-1_66;boost_property_tree-vc140-mt-gd;boost_property_tree-mt-gd-1_66;boost_property_tree-mt-gd;boost_property_tree-mt;boost_property_tree
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1767 ] Boost_FOUND = 1
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1928 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.66.0

  Boost include path: C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_66_0

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_property_tree

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: This link may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26749461/how-to-determine-the-boost-library-names-for-cmake .

Comment: Check this https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17575 . CMake 3.10 has no  support for boost 1.66 yet.

Comment: property_tree is header only, thus is not considered a component. You should just find_package(Boost), then `target_link_libraries( mytarget Boost::Boost)`. `Boost::Boost` is a meta target that grabs all the header only boost libraries.
You don't need to `set` anything, delete all that stuff.

Comment: @sbabbi I tried your solution, it give me the following error `Target "zia" links to target "Boost::Boost" but the target was not found.
  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an
  ALIAS target is missing?`

Comment: mmmm.. try `find_package(Boost COMPONENTS Boost)`? Not sure anymore..

Comment: Try `Boost::boost` instead of `Boost::Boost`, the second one shouldn't be uppercase