# No Additional Library Directories necessary for boost in VS 12.0

Tags: c++, boost

I just installed boost 1.58 for Visual Studio 12 and created an environment variable `BOOST_DIR` for the boost root directory. Furthermore, I added the folder `%BOOST_DIR%\stage\lib` to the `PATH` environment variable, where all the library files (DLL's + libs) were installed.

Now, in order to test the boost installation, I created a new project and added `$(BOOST_DIR)` to the Additional Include Directories. For some reason, this seems to be enough to get the project build and run successfully. For all other libraries, I was used to also include the library directory to Additional Library Directories and add the actually used libraries to `Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`.

Could someone please explain to me why this isn't necessary in the case of boost libraries?

This is the sample code I use to test whether boost works:

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    typedef std::istream_iterator<int> in;

    std::cout << "Type in any number: ";

    std::for_each(
        in(std::cin), in(), std::cout
        << (boost::lambda::_1 * 10)
        << "\nType in another number: ");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Boost libraries are header-only, which means you just need to include the header to use it. It is true for all the libs listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13604163/3854322).

As quoted from the [Boost Lambda documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/lambda/getting_started.html):

> The library consists of include files only, hence there is no installation procedure. The boost include directory must be on the include path.

Comment: You're welcome! Please consider accepting this answer if it answers your question

Comment: Sure! You answered so fast that it took a while until I was able to ;)