# CMake Boost Multiprecision not found

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

Here is my CMakeLists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project("pi-calc" VERSION 1.0)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS multiprecision)
add_executable(pi-calc main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(pi-calc PRIVATE Boost::boost Boost::multiprecision)
```

This is the main part of error message, removing CMake find_package failure Call Stacks

```
Could NOT find Boost (missing: multiprecision) (found version "1.67.0")
```

I have tried googling around for a solution but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many of Boost's libraries are header-only libraries, including the `multiprecision` library. You only need to explicitly call out the libraries in `COMPONENTS` that are *not* header-only, shown in the list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13604163/3987854).

If you need a header-only library, such as `multiprecision`, you will get this for free from the `Boost::boost` target, which includes all the Boost headers. There is no need to list any `COMPONENTS`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project("pi-calc" VERSION 1.0)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
add_executable(pi-calc main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(pi-calc PRIVATE Boost::boost)
```

Note, in CMake versions 3.15 and later, you should instead use the [`Boost::headers`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html) target, which supersedes the `Boost::boost` target.

Comment: Is using Boost::headers possible or even recommended in CMake 3.8? In what version of CMake was the Boost::headers target introduced.

Comment: @Toothless204 The `Boost::headers` target was introduced in CMake 3.15, so if you are using an earlier version, you should use `Boost::boost`. I'll update my response with this info.