# How to make a fifo special file in C?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, fifo

I have to use `mkfifo` in my C program in Ubuntu. But I have an error when I run the code: `no such file or directory` .

I think the problem because I have not set the `panel_fifo` environment variables. But I don't know how could I do this.

Here is my code I use to test this method:

```
char *myfifo="./sock/myfifo";

if (mkfifo(myfifo,0777)<0)
    perror("can't make it");

if (fd=open(myfifo,O_WRONLY)<0)
    perror("can't open it");
```

I compile this with:

`gcc gh.c -o gh`

When I run, I get this error message:

```
can't make it:no such file or directory
can't open it:no such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you created a directory `sock` in the current directory?  If not, that's the trouble. You are also missing parentheses around the assignment in the second `if` statement.

Comment: It's likely because the `sock` directory doesn't exist. Issue a `mkdir -p sock/myfifo` in the CWD and it should work after making the fixes suggested by @JonathanLeffler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [How can I create a directory tree in C++/Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675039/) for a general C (and C++) solution to creating a directory path.  For the immediate problem, that is overkill and a direct call to `mkdir()` suffices.

```
const char dir[] = "./sock";
const char fifo[] = "./sock/myfifo";
int fd;

if (mkdir(dir, 0755) == -1 && errno != EEXIST)
    perror("Failed to create directory: ");
else if (mkfifo(fifo, 0600) == -1 && errno != EEXIST)
    perror("Failed to create fifo: ");
else if ((fd = open(fifo, O_WRONLY)) < 0)
    perror("Failed to open fifo for writing: ");
else
{
    …use opened fifo…
    close(fd);
}
```

I'm assuming you have the correct headers included, of course (`<errno.h>`, `<fcntl.h>`, `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, `<sys/stat.h>`, `<unistd.h>`, I believe).

Note the parentheses around the assignment in the `if` that opens the FIFO.

Comment: Note that if `./sock/myfifo` is a directory, the `mkfifo()` will fail, but it will be the `open()` that reports an error (because the error from `mkfifo()` is EEXIST).  So, this isn't perfect in its error reporting, but given a sane starting position (`sock` either doesn't exist or is a directory — rather than, say, a file or FIFO; and `myfifo` either doesn't exist or is a FIFO), and assuming that something opens the FIFO for reading (e.g. I tested with `O_RDWR` instead of `O_WRONLY`), then it works OK.