# Open: no such file or directory with O_CREAT

Tags: c, file, system-calls

I'm trying to create a file using the open function, calling it as

```
dest_fd = open(fileLocation, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666)
```

When i run the code i get:

```
fileLocations: /tmp/folder/file.a
open: No such file or directory
```

(notice that i printed the value for fileLocation to make sure that it wasn't a relative path...)

I tried to do what i found on the other topics, but it doesn't seems to work, what could it be going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using `O_CREAT`, this error from `open` means that the *parent directory* of the file you're trying to create, or one of its parents, does not exist.  `open` will not create an entire directory hierarchy for you; you have to walk up the path calling `mkdir` as necessary.

In this case, I would do something like

```
if (mkdir("/tmp/chatty", 0777) && errno != EEXIST)
   perror_exit("mkdir /tmp/chatty");
dest_fd = open("/tmp/chatty/libchatty.a", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0666);
/* ... */
```

and not bother with recursing up and trying to create `/tmp` if the `mkdir` failed with `ENOENT` as well, because you probably don't have the privileges to do that, and in any case if `/tmp` doesn't exist something is horribly wrong with the computer.

Comment: if you need a function to ensure that the path leading to a file is created, see [How can I create a directory tree in C++/Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675039/how-can-i-create-directory-tree-in-c-linux) — where the code is C code that also compiles as C++ rather than the reverse.