# C FILE creation not working

Tags: c, file, fopen

I am writing the
function to insert the book. The function is **inslivros();**. Here is the code:

```
int inslivros()
{
    char livro[30];
    int categoria;
    printf("Qual é o nome do livro que vai inserir?\n-> ");
    gets(livro);
    printf("Qual é a categoria do livro?\n1- Romance\n2- História\n-> ");
    scanf("%d", &categoria);
    if(categoria == 1)
    {
        FILE *livros;

        livros = fopen("C:\Livros\inserelivros.txt", "w+");
        fputs(livro, livros);
        fclose(livros);

        FILE *romance;

        romance = fopen("C:\Livros\romance.txt", "w+");
        fputs(livro, romance);
        fclose(romance);

        system("cls");
        printf("Livro inserido com Sucesso!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        int escolha;
        system("cls");
        printf("Nome inválido!\n");
        printf("1- Adicionar livro\n0- Voltar para o menu\n-> ");
        scanf(escolha);
        switch(escolha)
        {
        case 1:
            system("cls");
            inslivros();
        case 2:
            system("cls");
            main();
        }
    }

}
```

When categoria == 1, the folder and file are not being created. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161535/discussion-on-question-by-rodrigo-silva-c-file-creation-not-working).

Comment: If you need to create a directory path, you can consider [How can I create a directory trein in C++/Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675039/how-can-i-create-directory-tree-in-c-linux/675193#675193)  The answer is both C and C++ code; it uses the `mkdir()` system call and should work OK on WIndows except for path separators (it should not be hard to treat backslashes as alternatives to slashes; Windows already handles slashes but conventionally uses backslashes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When categoria == 1, the **folder** and file are not being created. Where did I go wrong?

`fopen` doesn't create folders/directories for you - it only create files. So if `C:\Livros` doesn't exist when running the program, the program will fail.

To create the folder/directory look at `mkdir`

Comment: Thanks! My bad, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. implements most of the comments to the question
2. avoids recursion
3. separates the decision to continue adding entries from the actual adding of a new entry.
4. cleanly compiles
5. documents why each header file is being included
6. caveat: most items are properly error checked; however, the calls to `fputs()` should also be error checked

I'll leave it to you to use `mkdir` to create any missing directories.

Remember to check if the call to `mkdir` was successful, or not where the first time the program is run it may or may not be successful.  All following runs of the program should see `mkdir` fail.

And now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // perror(), printf(), fprintf(),
                     // fgets(), fputs(),
                     // fopen(), fclose()
#include <stdlib.h>  // system(), exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string.h>  // strlen(), strchr()

#define MAX_NOME_LEN 30

// prototypes
void inslivros( void );

int main( void )
{
    int escolha = 1;

    system("cls");


    while( escolha )
    {
        printf("1- Adicionar livro\n"
               "0- Voltar para o menu\n-> ");
        if( 1 != scanf( "%d", &escolha) )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "scanf for escolha failed\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, scanf successful

        switch(escolha)
        {
            case 1:
                inslivros();
                break;

            case 0:
                puts( "exiting" );
                break;

            default:  // user entered an invalid menu selection
                puts( "invalid menu selection, try again" );
                break;
        }  // end switch()
    } // end while()
} // end function: main


void inslivros()
{
    char livro[ MAX_NOME_LEN ];
    int categoria;

    printf( "Qual é o nome do livro que vai inserir?\n-> " );
    //gets(livro);
    if( ! fgets( livro, sizeof livro, stdin ) )
    {
        perror( "fgets for line to insert failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fgets successful

    // remove trailing newline
    char * newline;
    if( (newline = strchr( livro, '\n' ) ) )
    {
        *newline = '\0';
    }

    printf( "Qual é a categoria do livro?\n"
            "1- Romance\n"
            "2- História\n-> " );

    if( 1 != scanf("%d", &categoria) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf to input the 'categoria' failed\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //implied else, scanf successful

    FILE *livros = NULL;

    switch( categoria )
    {
        case 1:
            if( ! (livros = fopen("C:\\Livros\\inserelivros.txt", "a") ) )
            {
                perror( "fopen for inserelivros.txt failed" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            // implied else, fopen successful

            fputs(livro, livros);
            fclose(livros);

            FILE *romance;

            if( !(romance = fopen("C:\\Livros\\romance.txt", "a")) )
            {
                perror( "fopen for romance.txt failed" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }


            // implied else, fopen successful

            fputs( livro, romance );
            fclose( romance );

            system("cls");
            printf( "Livro inserido com Sucesso!\n" );
            break;

        case 0:
            printf( "Historia not yet implemented\n" );
            break;

        default:
            system("cls");
            //printf("Nome inválido!\n");
            printf( "invalid menu selection\n" );
            break;
    } // end switch()
} // end function: inslivros
```