# C Programming: How to create a parent directory and insert files manually?

Tags: c, file, directory

My goal is to, inside my C program, make a new directory. Within this directory, I want to create 15 simple text files. The part that I am stuck on is how to generate the 15 text files inside the newly created directory. I have created the new directory like this:

```
mkdir("new_dir", 0755);
```

But I am unsure of how to create a text file within it (in the same program). Any tips for this?

Comment: `snprintf(bigbuffer, sizeof(bigbuffer), "%s/%s", "new_dir", filename);` followed by a suitable open operation (`fopen()` or `open()`) using `bigbuffer` as the file name.  There are endless variations on this theme.

Comment: What is "bigbuffer" in this case?

Comment: `char bigbuffer[4096];` for example.

Comment: Incidentally, another option might be `chdir("new_dir")` (which I hope is actually a variable, not a constant string) after the `mkdir()`, and then create 15 files in the current directory.

Comment: Interesting. I will try this out and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are on some POSIX system. The C11 standard (read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) does not know about [directories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)) (an [abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science)) provided by your [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system)). If you are on Windows, it has a different [WinAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/apiindex/windows-api-list) (you should then use [CreateDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/FileAPI/nf-fileapi-createdirectorya))

First, your call to [mkdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html) could fail (for a variety of reasons, including the fact that the directory did already exist). And very probably, you actually want to create the directory in the home directory, or document that you are creating it in the current [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) (e.g. leave the burden of some appropriate and prior `cd` shell builtin to your user). Practically speaking, the directory path should be computed at runtime as a string (perhaps using [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) or [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html)).

So if you wanted to create a directory in the home directory of the user (remember that `~/foo/` is expanded by the [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) during globbing, see [glob(7)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))...; you need to fetch the home directory from [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)), you would code something like:

```
char pathbuf[256];
snprintf(pathbuf, sizeof(pathbuf), "%s/new_dir", getenv("HOME"));
```

to compute that string. Of course, you need to handle failure (of [getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html), or of `snprintf`). I am leaving these checks as an exercise. You might want to keep the result of `getenv("HOME")` in some [automatic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable).

Then you need to make the directory, and check against failure. At the very least (using [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) and see [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html)):

```
 if (mkdir (pathbuf, 0750)) { perror(pathbuf); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
```

BTW, the mode passed to `mkdir` might not allow every other user to write or access it (if it did, you could have some security [vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulnerability_(computing))). So I prefer `0750` to yours `0755`.

At last you need to create files inside it, perhaps using [fopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) before writing into them. So some code like

```
int i = somenumber();
snprintf(pathbuf, sizeof(pathbuf), 
         "%s/new_dir/file%d.txt", getenv("HOME"), i);
FILE* f = fopen(pathbuf, "w");
if (!f) { perror(pathbuf); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

As [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) wisely commented, there are other ways.

My recommendation is to document some convention. Do you want your program to create a directory in the current working directory, or to create it in some "absolute" path, perhaps related to the home directory of your user? If your program is started by some user (and is not [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) or doesn't have root permissions, see [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html)) it is not permitted to create directories or files at arbitrary places (see [hier(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html)).

If on Linux, you'll better read some system programming book like [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) or newer. If you use a different OS, you should read the documentation of its system API.

Comment: Another option is to take the name of the directory to be created as an argument to the program (like the `mkdir` command does) and try to create it.  If you need code to create the path to the directory, you can look at [How can I create a directory tree in C++/Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675039/how-can-i-create-directory-tree-in-c-linux) — which has a dual language C and C++ function (with test program) in the accepted answer.