# Sorting files based on their filetype

Tags: c, linux, unix

The program below is used to categorise files based on their filetypes, more precisely their extension. Command used for example `./sorting -f file1.jpg file2.txt file3.c` then it would create `jpg`, `txt`, and `c` folders and put the files inside.

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>

void *check(char *argv[]);
void *mkdir(char *argv[]);
void *mvdr(char *argv[]);
pid_t child;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t files[argc];  // inisialisasi awal
    int iret[argc];

    // 1. how many threads you need, setiap file
    //      -- setiap file setiap argc & argv

    // create thread every files
    if (argc == 1)
        return 0;

    if (strcmp(argv[1], "-f") == 0) {
        for (int i = 2; i < argc; ++i) {
            iret[i] = pthread_create( &files[i], NULL, check, argv[i]); // membuat thread pertama
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void *check(char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t move, make;
    int types = 0;
    int imv, imk;
    char type[80] = {0};
    char *tok = NULL;

    tok = strtok(argv, ".");
    while (tok) {
        strcpy(type, tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL, ".");

        imv = pthread_create(&make, NULL, mkdir, argv);

        imk = pthread_create(&move, NULL, mvdr, argv);

        pthread_join(mkdir, NULL);
        pthread_join(mvdr, NULL);
    }
}

void *mkdir(char *argv[]) {
    child = fork();

    if (child == 0) {
        char *mkdr[3] = { "mkdir", argv, NULL };
        execv("/usr/bin/mkdir", mkdr);
    }
}

void *mvdr(char *argv[]) {
    child = fork();

    if (child == 0) {
        char *mv[5] = { "mv", "-v", argv, argv, NULL };
        execv("/usr/bin/mv", mv);
    }
}
```

I'm using `execv` to make and move files. It has to be related to threading, pipes, or sockets. Do you have any clue how to solve it? Your help is much appreciated

Comment: Why threading?  Don't use `execv()` with threads if you can help it.  The sequencing for the `mvdr` and `mkdir` threads isn't self-evidently controlled.  You can use `mkdir()` system call instead of executing the `mkdir` command.  You could use `rename()` to rename the files — aka move it into the directory.  You should give a 'usage' message rather than exit silently when no arguments are provided.  Ditto if `argv[1]` is not `-f` (but it isn't really clear what the option is doing in the command line).

Comment: Hmmmph!  You're not using `fork()`, so the first thread to `execv()` replaces the whole program — including the other thread(s) — with whatever it executes.  You need to rethink what you're about.  IMO, you don't need threads at all, and you don't need `execv()` at all.  Were you to present code using either as a solution the problem, I'd reject the code outright.  Now, your exercise may have some other rules, but absent insanities like that, using either threads or `execv()` is simply wrong.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler because it's an exercise about it. how would you about go doing system calls on `mkdir()` ? Would you mind writing up some code for me? `-f` is supposed to check if it's files that is passed onto command line.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've updated the code with `fork()` and still nothing is going on.

Comment: It's way past bedtime for me, so I'm not going to write code now. If no-one has helped by the time I look again, maybe, but you really need to start over.  You use `mkdir(dirname, 0755);` or thereabouts to create a directory.  Note that `strtok()` butchers your command line arguments, so you're not going to be able to move files reliably after applying it to the file names.  You need to use a different function — probably `strrchr()` — to find the rightmost dot in the name (so `package-0.0.1.tar.gz` ends up in the `gz` directory). You really need to go back to first principles and start over.

Comment: As I said in my first comment, threads and (`fork()` and) `execv()` are a bad mix.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's really confusing and absurd using all of this. https://github.com/VYPRATAMA009/sisop-modul-3 that is my reference for all the code that I've used. As you can see it used `fork()` and `execv()` inside but without no clear explanation now there's this exercise that you're supposed to do and I just don't know where to start. I'll follow your suggestion to begin with. Have a good night and may you rest well, Jon

Comment: @JonathanLeffler are you going to write the code?

Comment: What do you think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61005311/15168) is?  It's the only answer I'm going to provide — I'm sorry, but neither threads nor `fork()` and `exec()` is appropriate as part of an answer to the problem being addressed.  If you must use them, then you may choose to do so.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it is very detailed and clear explanation. You would know I wouldn't in a lifetime could write that code if it isn't for your kind effort. As to `fork()` and `exec()` I wouldn't worry about it too much I'm still looking at your code and trying to grasp it all. Thank you so much Jon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear what constraints are placed on the classroom exercise, and my Indonesian is not as good as the OP's English, and Chrome didn't seem willing to translate the `README.md` file on the GitHub page https://github.com/VYPRATAMA009/sisop-modul-3.

Tackling the problem as described in the question (in terms of the desired result), there is no need to use either threads or `fork()` and `exec*()` to implement the program.

It is almost invariably a bad idea to mix threads with `fork()` and `exec*()` — choose multi-threading or multi-processing but not both at once.

The program needs to process the option (`-f` to check for regular files only; omit to move any file type), and then process any residual file names.  The name processing consists of checking for a regular file if desired, finding the extension with `strrchr()`, then creating a directory with that extension name, then formatting the name in the sub-directory, then renaming the file so it goes into the directory, and freeing the allocated memory.

```
#include "stderr.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static bool is_regular(const char *filename);
static void mk_directory(const char *dirname);
static void move_file(const char *filename);

static bool check_file = false;

static const char usestr[] = "[-f] file [...]";
static const char optstr[] = "f";

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int opt;
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, optstr)) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'f':
            check_file = true;
            break;
        default:
            err_usage(usestr);
            /*NOTREACHED*/
        }
    }

    if (optind == argc)
        err_usage(usestr);

    for (int i = optind; i < argc; i++)
        move_file(argv[i]);

    return 0;
}

static bool is_regular(const char *filename)
{
    struct stat sb;
    if (stat(filename, &sb) != 0)
        err_syserr("failed to get status of file '%s': ", filename);
    return S_ISREG(sb.st_mode);
}

static void mk_directory(const char *dirname)
{
    if (mkdir(dirname, 0755) != 0)
    {
        if (errno != EEXIST)
            err_syserr("failed to create directory '%s': ", dirname);
    }
}

static void move_file(const char *filename)
{
    char *dot = strrchr(filename, '.');
    if (check_file && !is_regular(filename))
    {
        err_remark("'%s' is not a regular file\n", filename);
        return;
    }
    if (dot == NULL || dot == filename || dot[1] == '\0')
    {
        err_remark("file '%s' does not have an extension\n", filename);
        return;
    }
    mk_directory(dot + 1);
    size_t namelen = strlen(dot + 1) + strlen(filename) + sizeof("/");
    char *buffer = malloc(namelen);
    if (buffer == NULL)
        err_syserr("failed to allocated %zu bytes memory: ", namelen);
    sprintf(buffer, "%s/%s", dot + 1, filename);
    if (rename(filename, buffer) != 0)
        err_syserr("failed to rename '%s' to '%s': ", filename, buffer);
    free(buffer);
}
```

This uses my error reporting functions which are available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.

Given a directory that starts out containing:

```
$ ls -la
total 56
drwxr-xr-x   15 jonathanleffler  staff   480 Apr  2 22:14 .
drwxr-xr-x  241 jonathanleffler  staff  7712 Apr  2 22:16 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 jonathanleffler  staff     0 Apr  2 22:12 .junk
-rw-r--r--    1 jonathanleffler  staff     0 Apr  2 22:12 .junk.
-rw-r--r--    1 jonathanleffler  staff  1036 Apr  2 22:06 binge.c
-rw-r--r--    1 jonathanleffler  staff   666 Apr  2 22:06 garbage.c
-rw-r--r--    1 jonathanleffler  staff  1772 Apr  2 21:11 junk-0.0.1.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--    1 jonathanleffler  staff  1772 Apr  2 21:10 junk-1.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 jonathanleffler  staff  1772 Apr  2 21:10 junk-2.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 jonathanleffler  staff     0 Apr  2 22:12 junk.
-rw-r--r--    1 jonathanleffler  staff  1772 Apr  2 21:10 junk.c
drwxr-xr-x    3 jonathanleffler  staff    96 Apr  2 22:04 junk.dir
prw-r--r--    1 jonathanleffler  staff     0 Apr  2 22:10 junk.fifo
lrwxr-xr-x    1 jonathanleffler  staff     8 Apr  2 21:12 junk.lnk -> junk.dir
-rw-r--r--    1 jonathanleffler  staff   812 Apr  2 22:06 trash.c
$
```

running the program (`mf29` compiled from `mf29.c`) yields:

```
$ mf29 -f .j* *
mf29 -f .j* *
mf29: file '.junk' does not have an extension
mf29: file '.junk.' does not have an extension
mf29: file 'junk.' does not have an extension
mf29: 'junk.dir' is not a regular file
mf29: 'junk.fifo' is not a regular file
mf29: 'junk.lnk' is not a regular file
$ ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   11 jonathanleffler  staff   352 Apr  2 22:37 .
drwxr-xr-x  241 jonathanleffler  staff  7712 Apr  2 22:16 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 jonathanleffler  staff     0 Apr  2 22:12 .junk
-rw-r--r--    1 jonathanleffler  staff     0 Apr  2 22:12 .junk.
drwxr-xr-x    6 jonathanleffler  staff   192 Apr  2 22:37 c
drwxr-xr-x    3 jonathanleffler  staff    96 Apr  2 22:37 gz
-rw-r--r--    1 jonathanleffler  staff     0 Apr  2 22:12 junk.
drwxr-xr-x    3 jonathanleffler  staff    96 Apr  2 22:04 junk.dir
prw-r--r--    1 jonathanleffler  staff     0 Apr  2 22:10 junk.fifo
lrwxr-xr-x    1 jonathanleffler  staff     8 Apr  2 21:12 junk.lnk -> junk.dir
drwxr-xr-x    4 jonathanleffler  staff   128 Apr  2 22:37 txt
$
```

Then reinstating the moved files and running again without the `-f` option yields:

```
$ mv ?/* ??/* ???/* ????/* .
$ rmdir ? ?? ??? ????
$ mf29 .j* *
mf29: file '.junk' does not have an extension
mf29: file '.junk.' does not have an extension
mf29: file 'junk.' does not have an extension
$ ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   11 jonathanleffler  staff   352 Apr  2 22:42 .
drwxr-xr-x  241 jonathanleffler  staff  7712 Apr  2 22:16 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 jonathanleffler  staff     0 Apr  2 22:12 .junk
-rw-r--r--    1 jonathanleffler  staff     0 Apr  2 22:12 .junk.
drwxr-xr-x    6 jonathanleffler  staff   192 Apr  2 22:42 c
drwxr-xr-x    3 jonathanleffler  staff    96 Apr  2 22:42 dir
drwxr-xr-x    3 jonathanleffler  staff    96 Apr  2 22:42 fifo
drwxr-xr-x    3 jonathanleffler  staff    96 Apr  2 22:42 gz
-rw-r--r--    1 jonathanleffler  staff     0 Apr  2 22:12 junk.
drwxr-xr-x    3 jonathanleffler  staff    96 Apr  2 22:42 lnk
drwxr-xr-x    4 jonathanleffler  staff   128 Apr  2 22:42 txt
$
```

If you provide names with multiple pathname components, this will usually fail:

```
$ ../mf29 ~/src/cmd/timecmd.c
mf29: failed to rename '/Users/jonathanleffler/src/cmd/timecmd.c' to 'c//Users/jonathanleffler/src/cmd/timecmd.c': error (2) No such file or directory
$
```

There are various ways that could be fixed — it depends on the desired result.  The POSIX function [`basename()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/basename.html) could be useful.  The function [`mkpath()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/675193/15168) could be useful too.